# DataFrame Concatenation Issue

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, concatenation

**First I created two dataframes using a 3-dimensional list.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
list= [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],[22,23,24], 
[25,26,27]]]
narray = np.array(list)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(narray)
df1  = pd.DataFrame.from_records(narray)
```

**Then I concatenated the dataframes using:**

```
frames = [df, df1]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

**When I run the above code, I get the desired concatenated DataFrame. But when I try to do the same using a for loop, I run into an error.**

```
frames = []
for i in range(2):
    list= [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27]]]
    narray = np.array(list)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(narray)
    frames = [frames, df]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

**The error I get is:**

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: where is i in the for loop? and frames is an empty list and not a dataframe. kindly check ur code again?

Comment: your concatenating list and data frame. which wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from the item appending to the list:

```
frames = []
for i in range(2):
    list= [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27]]]
    narray = np.array(list)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(narray)
    frames = [frames, df] # WRONG!
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Instead, try substituting `frames = [frames, df]` by `frames += [df]` or `frames.append(df)`:

```
frames = []
for i in range(2):
    list= [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27]]]
    narray = np.array(list)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(narray)
    frames += [df] # RIGHT!
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this- append to frame instead of assigning

```
for i in range(2):
    list= [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]],[[19,20,21], 
          [22,23,24],[25,26,27]]]
    narray = np.array(list)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(narray)
frames.append(df)
result = pd.concat(frames)
```